# Reset gThumb right panel size to default

Tags: gthumb

Usually right panel with actions takes around 20 percent of the screen. Somehow, now it takes around 70, and takes too much place on the screen. I don't know how it happened (it's my dad's computer) but interested to know how I can reset this setting back to default.

I've tried playing with view menu items, but with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove its user config files and it will reset back to default view.

```
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/gthumb
```

and

```
rm -rf ~/.config/gthumb
```

Comment: first - not found path, second - deleted - nothing happened :(